# TS2339: How do I create a Typescript interface for props for a React component with rest params?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

e.g. my component:

```
const Link: React.SFC<LinkPropTypes> = ({ url, children, ...rest }) => {
  {
    return isUrlInSinglePageApplicationUrlWhiteList(url) ? (
      <ReactRouterLink to={url} {...rest}>
        {children}
      </ReactRouterLink>
    ) : (
      <ReactRouterLink to={url} {...rest} target="_self">
        {children}
      </ReactRouterLink>
    )
  }
}

interface LinkPropTypes  {
  url: string
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export default Link
```

gives the compile error

`TS2339: Property 'className' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & LinkPropTypes & { children?: ReactNode; }`

when invoked from another TS component

```
<Link url={promotion.PromoKey} className="view-offer-link">
          <FormattedMessage id="viewOffer" /> <Icon type="arrow-right" />
        </Link>
```

The closest way I've found of getting rid of the compiler errors is to extend from `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>` (found [here](https://github.com/Mercateo/react-with-typescript))

```
interface LinkPropTypes extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  url: string
  children: React.ReactNode
}
```

although I'm not quite sure why or if this is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to extend `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>` is a good one if you want to allow any HTML element property to be specified on you class. `React.HTMLAttributes` represent the properties for all html elements so you will get more then just  `className`. You could also explicitly define what extra properties you want (such as className) although that might be tedious, and if you want to allow any property without any check to be specified on the tag, you could also use:

```
interface LinkPropTypes {
  url: string
  children: React.ReactNode
  [name: string]: any;
}

<Link url={""} className="view-offer-link"> </Link>
```

Comment: Do you have a reference to how the [name: string]: any syntax works?

Comment: @DamianGreen https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html